# Trying to verify the solution to a lambda calculus equation

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am going through the following introduction to lambda calculus :

http://www.cse.chalmers.se/research/group/logic/TypesSS05/Extra/geuvers.pdf

At page 12 , the following has been asked to prove

$ \exists $ $ G $ $ \forall X $ such that

$GX$ = $GG$

This means to find a function which takes a function as an argument and returns the same expression irrespective of the function .

The book posits the solution to be $ G $ = $Y$ $(  \lambda gx. gg) $

On trying to verify this I first evaluated the L.H.S to be

$ GX $ = $ Y ( \lambda gx.gg ) $ $X$.

Now $X$ being the argument will be picked up by the first bound variable  so .

$L.H.S $ = $ Y ( \lambda x . XX) $ =  $( \lambda x . XX)$  $ Y ( \lambda x . XX) 
$ = $ Y ( \lambda x .$ $ Y ( \lambda x . XX)$ $ Y ( \lambda x . XX)$)

Here  due to the presence of the form $ YF $ , I can carry on the reduction continuously  by replacinf $YF$ with $FYF$

$R.H.S$ =  $Y$ $(  \lambda gx. gg) $ $Y$ $(  \lambda gx. gg) $
           = $Y$$ \lambda  x.$ $( Y(  \lambda gx. gg) $ $Y(  \lambda gx. gg)) $

Now similarly  the reduction can be carried on further by again consuming the first $g$ that comes in the expression with  $Y(  \lambda gx. gg)) $ and this can on perpetually and it will look like   $ Y ( \lambda x .$ $ Y ( \lambda x . XX)$ $ Y ( \lambda x . XX)$).....
So I couldn't completely ascertain that they ( L.H.S and R.H.S) will turn out to be equal but I can  see that L.H.S and R.H.S are going to be infinitely long  and will resemble each other more and more as the number of reductions go on since  the $ g$ 's in the R.H.S will continually get replaced .

Is this logic correct ? If not , where did I err ?

P.S. : On a general and on a lighter note , how are this lambda calculus equations solved ? (They look analogous to differential equations ).

Answer (score 3):

> On trying to verify this I first evaluated the L.H.S to be
>
> $ GX $ = $ Y ( \lambda gx.gg ) $ $X$.
>
> Now $X$ being the argument will be picked up by the first bound
>   variable  so .
>
> $L.H.S $ = $ Y ( \lambda x . XX) $

This is where you went wrong, and the reason is that you've got the association the wrong way round. $Y ( \lambda gx.gg ) X$ means $(Y ( \lambda gx.gg )) X$.

Taking that into account, the only evaluation step possible is to apply $Y$, giving $$( \lambda gx.gg )(Y ( \lambda gx.gg )) X$$ which is $( \lambda gx.gg )GX$, from which the desired conclusion is immediate.

Comment: : The last expression will give $ ( \lambda x. GG) X $ , right ? This will result in $GG$ if   $x$ is not there in G right ?

Comment: @AgniveshSingh Correct. There is no need to require "if $x$ is not there in $G$" since we know that $x$ is not free in $G$, which is a closed term by definition.